# How to ignore phpstatus.php connection in Xdebug + PhpStorm while working with local projects with DDEV?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, ddev

I receive redundant incoming connections from Xdebug (request uri: `/phpstatus`, file path on server: `/var/www/phpstatus.php`) while working with DDEV despite there are not breakpoints in the `phpstatus.php` file.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the issue a correct mapping to project files and "Ignore external connections through unregistered server configuration" are required.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check "Skipped Paths" functionality as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/skipped-paths.html